How do I prevent Vite/Rollup from amending my js filename with the number 2 becuase it has the same name as a css file?
I have php-based API that serves HTML, CSS and JS files to another site for interactive visuals. Bundling was originally done by Mix. I am trying to switch over to Vite.
The issue I am having is that the API was built around the blade.php file, js and css files all having the same names. But when I use Vite to bundle my js and css files to a dist file, it is adding the no. 2 to either my js file or css file.
I found this issue, but there was no resolution.
Note that this is not a Laravel app. I am only using Blade files for templating.
Here is my config:
function getFiles (dir:string):string[] {
  // get all 'files' in this directory
  // filter directories
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(file => {
      return fs.statSync(`${dir}/${file}`).isFile();
  });
};

export default defineConfig({
    root: './app',
    build: {
        outDir: './../public/dist',
        rollupOptions: {
            input: [... jsFiles.map(file => `/js/${file}`), ... cssFiles.map(file => `/scss/graphs/${file}`)],
            output: {
                entryFileNames: 'js/[name].js',
                assetFileNames: 'css/[name].css'
            },
        },
    },
    plugins:[
        usePHP({
            entry:['views/layouts/main.blade.php']
        })
    ],
    server:{
        proxy:{
            '/': {
                target: 'http://cccdata.test',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    },
    css: {
        postcss: {
          plugins: [
            require('tailwindcss'),
            require('autoprefixer'),
          ],
        },
    }
    

})

Any idea how I can prevent this from happening?
Update:
Created a similar enough scaffolding on Stackblitz. However I cannot reproduce the issue I am having. Directory structure is similar enough. No PHP obviously, but I doubt that is the issue since it has nothing to do with the bundling phase.
I'll also add that the appending issue is only happening for about a dozen of these files. I can't find a pattern among them.

you could prepare a reproducible example on stackblitz

Just added a link to stackblitz. Unfortunately I have yet to reproduce the issue I am having.
